# getting the plain C++ implementation of a QT code

Tags: c++, qt, signals

I was trying to figure out how this code will loke like in plain C++ without any dependency so I was using the `moc` compiler but apparently I'm wrong.

moc always returns

```
main.cpp:0: Note: No relevant classes found. No output generated.
```

the code is

> ```
> #include <QApplication>
> #include <QWidget>
> #include <QPushButton>
>
> class MyButton : public QWidget
> {
>  public:
>      MyButton(QWidget *parent = 0);
> };
>
> MyButton::MyButton(QWidget *parent)
>     : QWidget(parent)
> {   
>   QPushButton *quit = new QPushButton("Quit", this);
>   quit->setGeometry(50, 40, 75, 30);
>
>   connect(quit, SIGNAL(clicked()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));
> }
>
>
> int main(int argc, char *argv[])
> {
>   QApplication app(argc, argv);  
>
>   MyButton window;
>
>   window.resize(250, 150);
>   window.move(300, 300);
>   window.setWindowTitle("button");
>   window.show();
>
>   return app.exec();
> }
> ```
>
> from http://www.zetcode.com/gui/qt4/firstprograms/

In general terms I'm interested in creating my own signal slot system using only the C++ standard library ( no boost signal, no QT, no nothing else ) so I'm doing this for research purpose and I'm only interested on the infrastructure about signals and slots.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the `Q_OBJECT` macro to the **private section of your class**, so `moc` converts it.

```
class MyButton : public QWidget
{
 Q_OBJECT
 public:
     MyButton(QWidget *parent = 0);
};
```

[Here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#Q_OBJECT) is what the documentation says.

Comment: the code is ok but it's not the complete program, how i can inquire the broad view about signals and slots ?

Comment: [This](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) article should help you.